# Angular2 - Get component light DOM innerHTML / child nodes

Tags: typescript, angular

Let's say I have a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: '<div>foo</div>'
})
export class Foo {}
```

And I consume it in another component like this:

```
<foo>
  <h1>some inner HTML</h1>
</foo>
```

**How can I find out if `Foo` has any child elements in the light DOM?**

I want to get ahold of `<h1>some inner HTML</h1>`.

*Option 1* - `@ContentChildren()`: This cannot be used to query arbitrary elements; currently only Angular 2 components or variables (`#foo`) may be queried in this way. I don't want to have to attach a variable to the inner elements if I can avoid it.

*Option 2* - `elementRef.nativeElement`: I can inject `ElementRef` into the `Foo` component, but by the time the component has instantiated (in the constructor), the inner elements have already been removed, and it will be empty. Later in the life cycle (e.g. `ngAfterViewInit()`) the inner elements will just be the shadow DOM (i.e. `<div>foo</div>`).

Any other methods that I am missing?

**Use Case**

To give some context about why I want to do this, I am creating a library component which has a default template, which may be replaced by a custom template if the user decides. So my default template looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="hasTemplate"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
<div *ngIf="!hasTemplate"><!-- the default template --></div>
```

I need some way to set `hasTemplate` to `true` if there is HTML inside the `<foo>..</foo>` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can switch to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` then the content will be in the light DOM
- You can add a wrapper element around `<div #wrapper><ng-content><ng-content><div>` then you can get the elements from the "shadow DOM"

Comment: Doesn't using `ViewEncapsulation.Native` mean that I am limited to browsers that implement shadow DOM? I am building a re-usable library and need as wide support as possible. Other than that - yes, it works as you say.

Comment: Yes, you would need to add web-components polyfills on browsers that don't support it natively. Does the wrapper approach work as well? You could create a feature request in the Angular repo to add support for querying content children from the `ng-content` element.

Comment: @Guenter - Ok, that makes the first option a no-go I'm afraid. Cannot get the wrapper approach to work. I added some more info to the question to clarify my use case. I think since I have an `ngIf` on my "custom" template wrapper, it just appears as `<!--template bindings={}-->` when I try to inspect its contents, and `ContentChildren('wrapper')` yields `null`.

I think an issue on angular/angular is probably the way to go.

Comment: You would need to use `ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper;` because the wrapper is outside of `<ng-content>` and then `access the children with `wrapper.nativeElement.children` (in or after `ngAfterViewInit()`)

Comment: Excellent - that works as long as I remove the `ngIf`, which is actually not needed around the `<ng-content>` tag. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `*ngIf` removes the elements from the DOM. If you use instead `[hidden]="!isVisible"` then you can still query the children even when `isVisible` is `false`.